# Haskell: How to pack text for Data.Text.Intertnal.Text

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use the [smtp-mail](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/smtp-mail) module.

I am trying to construct the `Address` data type which is of:

```
Address  
addressName  :: Maybe Text   
addressEmail :: Text
```

with overloaded strings I can construct the `Address` no problem. However when I try to pass a String to it and `pack` it, I cannot seem to find the correct `pack` function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import Network.Mail.SMTP

testAddress :: String
testAddress = "me@email.com"

-- this works fine
myAddress1 :: Address
myAddress1 = Address Nothing ("me@email.com")

myAddress2 :: Address
myAddress2 = Address Nothing (T.pack testAddress)
```

gives error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Data.Text.Internal.Text'
              with actual type `T.Text'
  NB: `T.Text' is defined in `Data.Text.Internal.Lazy'
      `Data.Text.Internal.Text' is defined in `Data.Text.Internal'
* In the second argument of `Address', namely
    `(T.pack testAddress)'
  In the expression: Address Nothing (T.pack testAddress)
  In an equation for `myAddress2':
      myAddress2 = Address Nothing (T.pack testAddress)
```

Comment: Have you tried `import qualified Data.Text as T`?

Comment: @melpomene, yes and that does not work either

Comment: According to the source of [link] (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-mail-0.4.11/docs/src/Network-Mail-Mime.html#Address), Address use strict version of Text (Data.text), @melpomene suggestion seems work.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to be using `Data.Text.Lazy` but after testing it out, as recommended by @melpomene you need to change:

`--import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import qualified Data.Text as T`

if you look at the `Address` definition it expects a `Text` to be from `Data.Text` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/smtp-mail-0.1.4.6/docs/Network-Mail-SMTP-Types.html#t:Address